# Creating Instances of a Parent Class with a Variable Number of Subclasses which Modify the Parent Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, discord.js

As a beginning note, I'm writing a discord bot with Discord.js. And sorry for the potentially confusing title.

The basic functionality of the bot is that it helps multiple users play card games together, say for example Go Fish.
I'd like to eventually add the functionality for server admin to write and add their own "mods," (modifications) to spice up whatever game they'd like. In this case, someone could make it so that the game would require either 4 or 2 cards to complete a set in Go Fish, depending on if the mod is enabled for a specific instance of the game, or perhaps modify the `drawCard()` method to continue drawing cards until the player gets a card they already have at least one of. (or honestly do whatever with the original game, doesn't matter.)

As of my current code, I have a few basic classes, with a specific class `coreGame`, and then different "base games" which `extend coreGame`, providing basic functionality for all types of card games. When a user wants to play a game, I won't know which mods are available, since they're server-specific. The best I think can do is create a new instance of `baseGoFish` (My original, unmodified implementation of the base game which isn't server-specific)
I'm thinking that mods would extend the base game, like `class modExample extends baseGoFish {...}`, but I'm not sure how I would create an instance of the modded game, and even less sure if there were multiple mods.

As another note, I think have to call mods' methods twice, once before the base game's actual code, (so that it can choose to cancel the base game's methods, as if it were an event, or do its own thing unrelated to the base game), and once after, so that mods could edit what the base game just did. This specific part seems pretty jank and likely to break, so what would be a better solution here as well?

I've looked briefly into mixins, and those seem like they'll help here, but I'm unsure of how to properly implement them, as I've never used them before (much less used javascript with classes.)

Comment: A way this could be possible is to have set ‘mods’ that can be implemented by commands, e.g. <prefix>goFish add <modname> - I think it would be way too difficult to do custom commands, because the admin would have to have previous experience of JavaScript, and would have to know your code, and variable names. Unless you set out changes, I don’t see how you could make custom mods.

Comment: Yes, I was planning on making my code public, so that admin could view the source and design things from there. I don't mind knowing javscript being a requirement to mod the game either.

Comment: Okay, but be careful, if your code is open source, I don’t see how you could run the same instance of the bot under one name, people would simply skid the code for other bots, but it’s up to you.

Comment: @Bedrockbreaker I suggest you write an API that people could use to mod your core games, that could be public while still having your code private, that's the best option imo